# Controller not being found - Magento

Tags: magento, controller

I'm new to Magento so sry if it's a newbie question. I have a module Foo_Bar. In the controllers folder, I have another folder named 'Catalog'. And inside there, I have my CategoryController.php.

Here's my `CategoryController.php`:

```
class Foo_Bar_Catalog_CategoryController extends Mage_Core_Controller_Front_Action
{
    public function viewAction()
    {
        echo 'It worked!';
    }
}
```

and my config.xml is as follows:

```
<config>
    <frontend>
        <routers>
            <foo_bar>
                <use>standard</use>
                <args>
                    <module>Foo_Bar</module>
                    <frontName>foo</frontName>
                </args>
            </foo_bar>
        </routers>
    </frontend>
</config>
```

My modules's enabled for sure and it's showing up in Configuration Manager.

The problem is when I go to http://magento.localhost.com/magento/foo/catalog/category/view, I get 'Sorry page cannot be found'. When I put the controller in the 'controllers' folder (not under catalog) and rename the classname of the controller, http://magento.localhost.com/magento/foo/category/view works.

The problem seems to be related to having a folder in the controllers folder. What's wrong with this approach?

Thanks a lot!

Krt_Malta

Answer (score 2, accepted):

have you tried this url: http://magento.localhost.com/magento/foo/catalog_category/view/ ?